# Speed up rendering of page with many custom directives in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm currently rebuilding an enterprise app in AngularJS. It has a multi-page form with thousands of fields, which are all wrapped in custom directives (for validation, formatting, and standardization purposes) based on the field type.

I've tried to optimize these directives as best as possible (one time binding, `ng-if` where possible, `lazy-ng-if`, no `$watch` functions, and minimal `$rootScope.broadcast`'s), but I'm still faced with a several second delay when loading each form page (about 50-or-so fields each) with `ui-router`. Looking at all my performance measurements, it seems like the delay is coming from angular compiling and rendering all these directives.

So my question is, how do I make these directives render faster? Is there a way I can compile/render the top section of my form and make it usable before the rest loads? Right now with `ui-router`, it seems like nothing appears until everything on the form is rendered/compiled.

Comment: I should  mention that I've definitely narrowed it down to being a directive compilation issue. The time it takes the page to load with ui-router correlates very closely with the number of these form directives it contains. A page with 10 will load near-instantly on localhost, but the regular pages with 50 take a few seconds.

Comment: The first thing to check is how much $digest cycles is run?

Comment: Check out Batarang web inspector extension for Chrome, to help with debugging: https://github.com/angular/batarang

Comment: Without seeing the code, it is nearly impossible to guess where the problems are. Can you provide a code example of what you're dealing with?